# Bash: Get child process name

Tags: c++, linux, bash, parent-child

I'm new with bash. I'm have this little code:
**bash.sh**

```
./mama
```

**mama.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("./shvili");
  while(1){}
}
```

**shvili.cpp**

```
int main()
{
  while(1){}
}
```

As it shows me `mama` is parent of `shvili` process. I have situation like this where I don't know exactly the name of child process. So my question is, How can I get the PID of child process from c++?(It would be more comfortable for me to get the name of process).

Comment: why not use fork + exec instead of system call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to at least check via bash in case "situation like this where I don't know exactly the name of child process" but knows the name of the parent process assumed to be unique, one can use in `bash` based on `ps`, `grep`, `sed` (to remove leading space for smaller pids), `tr` (to squeeze multiple consecuting spaces into one), and `cut`:

```
$> cat foo_bar.sh 
#! /bin/bash
sleep 120

$> ./foo_bar.sh &
[1] 89239

$> ps -eo pid,ppid,args|grep -e " $(ps -eo pid,args| grep foo_bar.sh| grep -v grep| sed s/^\ //g |cut -f 1 -d ' ') "|grep -v foo_bar.sh| sed s/^\ //g | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 1,3 -d ' '
89241 sleep
```

Thus the unique name of the parent process is used to determine the parent pid:

```
$> ps -eo pid,args| grep foo_bar.sh| grep -v grep| sed s/^\ //g |cut -f 1 -d ' '
89239
```

This evaluated in a sub process (`$(...)`) is used to grep the correct line from another `ps` call to determine the seeked pid of child and name (without additional arguments and without prior knowledge of the childs name.

Note - as usual in bash some spaces are important - the added space at the end of the search pattern:

```
... grep " $(ps -eo pid,args| grep foo_bar.sh| grep -v grep| cut -f 1 -d ' ') " ...
```

This helps avoid false positives, like when a parent pid is 123, without padding with spaces this would match many pids that contain these digits like 1234, 12345, 1123, ...

**Update** (reacting on comment): In case parent process is `a_mama` (forking off `a_shvili` sub process) and it is the only process with that name on the machine, then the following should work:

```
$> p_proc="a_mama"
$> ps -eo pid,ppid,args|grep -e " $(ps -eo pid,args| grep ${p_proc}| grep -v grep| sed s/^\ //g | cut -f 1 -d ' ') "|grep -v ${p_proc}| sed s/^\ //g | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 1,3 -d ' '
12346 a_shvili
```

Comment: I know this is not a C++ solution, but as noted might come in handy for test or when no access to source code is given.

Comment: after I changed `sleep 120` to `mama` `ps -eo pid,ppid,args|grep -e " $(ps -eo pid,args| grep foo_bar.sh| grep -v grep| cut -f 1 -d ' ') "|grep -v foo_bar.sh| cut -f 1,3 -d ' '` gives me output with lot of PIDs

Comment: Oh, I see, but `foo_bar.sh` was a mock standing in for your `mama` **parent** process and thus `sleep 120` would be the **child** (`shvili` in your question), so you should start `mama` (as parent) in the background or then in another terminal replace `foo_bar.sh` in my recipe with `mama`(in the hope it matches not too many process names running ...

Comment: That didn't help. Still lot of PIDs.

Comment: Please try again updated the recipe to safguard against spaces added by ps to pad smaller pids. PS: When no match is found of parent, grep matches empty pattern agains ps result thus giving all entries ...

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) to get the pid of a particular process.

Example

```
char line[LEN];
FILE *cmd = popen("pidof...", "r");

fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);

pclose(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know the name of the child process it is `shvili`, how can you start it and not know its name.

If you with to know the `PID` of the child, then do not use `system`. `system` is not a well behaved procedure, do not use it.

Instead use `fork` and `exec`:

In parent do:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == -1) {
   //fork failed do something about it
} else if (child_pid == 0) {
   //this runs for child
   execl("shvili", NULL);
   //if you get here then exec errored
} else {
   //This runs for parent
   //child_pid has child pid
   //Add parent code hear.
   wait(…);
}
```

Explanation:

- the first branch of the ifs runs if fork errors.
- else

  - In 2 separate processes:
  - the second branch runs for the child.
  - and the third branch runs for the parent.

Comment: I showed just an example how situation might be. I have a process which has different child on different distro(because it executes different bash script when it starts), I want to get the name of child process.

Comment: You still must know it, to call `system` or `exec`, is it in a variable? Which parts know?, which parts need to know?

Comment: Its just an example. In reality I have a process which creates session for different user. On gnome it's child is `init --user` but for example on centos its `gnome-session` process, I have to write a code which would give me which of these is the child